# Chaining multiple predicates for filter in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, predicate

I am new to functional programming. I want to chain multiple predicates for filter.

Suppose I have list of names which i want to filter with...

```
 val names = List("cat","dog","elephant")


 //Currently I am doing like this, this is not dynamic,The list of name will come dynamically
 objects.filterSubjects(string => {
    string.endsWith("cat") ||   string.endsWith("dog") ||   string.endsWith("elephant")
  })
```

How to make the above line dynamic,so that I  dont have to write it. Iwant to create it according to the list of names user provides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `exists` to check if some predicate is fulfilled for any value in a collection (OR on predicate at every element) or `forall` to check if predicate id filfilled for all values (AND on predicate at every element).

You could use it for example like this:

```
val names = List("cat", "dog", "elephant")
val predicate = (s: String) => names.exists(s.endsWith _)
objects.filter(predicate)
```

Comment: I think it would work without underscore:  `names.exists(s.endsWith)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `exists` to check if you dynamic list `names` has such values.

```scala
val names = List("cat","dog","elephant")
val objects = List("stringcat", "dog", "dognot")

objects.filter(string => {
    names.exists(n => string.endsWith(n))
})
// List(stringcat, dog)
```

(https://scastie.scala-lang.org/mgzlIGfHTRaN28TEetM5DA)